# quitar escalado automatico en marcadores de google maps (API google maps)

Tags: google-maps-v3

estoy realizando un proyecto con google maps en el que tengo que integrar una ruta y dos marcadores, lo que quiero hacer es que al hacer zoom los marcadores no puedan cambiar de tamaño, no se puedan escalar.
no sé si lo que quiero hacer se puede. llevo más de una semana intentando hacerlo y buscando informacion, soy nuevo con la API.
muchas gracias

Comment: Encontré un hilo en el que hacen lo contrario es decir al acercar cambiar el tamaño,quizá te sirva de algo o lo puedas adaptar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14851641/change-marker-size-in-google-maps-api-v2/14851813

Comment: Hola user, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Lo más importante es haberlo intentado. Sobre tu intento nos contextualizas en los problemas concretos que tienes y sobre ello podemos ayudarte. Si no lo has intentado, investiga y prueba. Después has de [edit] la pregunta para añadir la información que falta segun [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo.

Comment: el problema es que no estoy haciendo el proyecto con android, estoy con javascript y html